# How to make a VRT with an input raster containing multi bands?

Tags: gdal, multi-band, gdalbuildvrt

I have 3 different rasters each containing 2 bands. Such as :

- Input1.tif B1 B2
- Input2.tif B1 B2
- Input3.tif B1 B2

I want to build a vrt with the B2 of each raster. With gdalbuildvrt I always get this warning :
Warning 1: Input1.tif has 2 bands. Only the first one will be taken into account in the -separate case

for the moment, I launch :
`gdalbuildvrt -separate output.vrt Input1.tif Input2.tif Input3.tif`

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vrt file is just a descriptive XML file. `gdalbuildvrt` does the heavy lifting for you to create one, but you can edit `output.vrt` afterwards with any text editor.

If you replace instances of `<SourceBand>1</SourceBand>` with `<SourceBand>2</SourceBand>`, you will point to the 2nd band of each input raster rather than the first.

A full guide to all sorts of fancy things you can specify manually inside a vrt file can be found at https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find a better solution than the following, which uses intermediate vrts :

1) extract the one band raster vrt's that you need, e.g.

```
gdalbuildvrt -b 2 input2b2.vrt input2.tif
```

2) build the multiband raster

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate combi.vrt input1b2.vrt input2b2.vrt input3b2.vrt
```